# Help testing the predictive quality of a binomial GLM (currently attempting using the "caret" package)

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, prediction, caret

Hello world (sorry for the novel; if you read this, I appreciate it!),

I'm running into a question that is probably a mixture of how to approach a problem of modeling and the technical difficulties in executing my model and prediction in R. At the bottom of this message I've included my dataset and the column names. This is my first attempt to create a reproducible dataset, so please let me know if I've done this incorrectly.

Some background:
I am attempting to find the best model to predict dispersal (this is a binary outcome: "dispersed" and "recruited"). I've coded "dispersed" as 1 and "recruited" as 0 in my dataframe. One issue is that dispersal is a rare event and I have a relatively small dataset. Additionally I have a few NAs for two of my potential predictors (fledge date and body condition). This is a project for a graduate course, so the ultimate fit of the model (which will likely be poor due to the sample size) isn't of scientific significance. However, I will be adding to this dataset for my thesis and want to understand the best approach.

What I have so far:
I did preliminary data exploration with univariate relationships and a correlation matrix. I then fit a number of binomial GLMs and selected the best models using AIC. Diagnostic plots for my models show deviation from normality at the extremes and a definite violation of the assumption of homogeneity of variances. It's good that I know this, but again, there aren't scientific stakes to the fit of the model.

My top three models are:

```
ATPU_NDP_glm15=glm(Dispersed_Or_Recruited~Fledge_Date+Age_made_decision+No_islands_prospected, 
                   family=binomial, control = list(maxit = 50), data=ATPU_knownsex_data_NA_FD)

ATPU_NDP_glm17=glm(Dispersed_Or_Recruited~No_islands_prospected+Age_made_decision+
Body_Condition, family=binomial, control = list(maxit = 50), data=ATPU_knownsex_data)

ATPU_NDP_glm19=glm(Dispersed_Or_Recruited~No_islands_prospected+Age_made_decision+
Breeding_Success+ Fledge_Date, family=binomial, control = list(maxit = 50), data=ATPU_knownsex_data)
```

I calculated overdispersion for each model (which is expectedly high):

```
resid.ssq <- sum(residuals(ATPU_NDP_glm15,type="pearson")^2)  ## sum of squares of Pearson 
resid.df <- nrow(ATPU_knownsex_data)-length(coef(ATPU_NDP_glm15))   ## estimated resid df (N-p)
resid.ssq/resid.df        ## ratio should be approx 1
#very overdispersed; k = 0.115
```

I calculated pseudo R^2 in the "descr" package

```
LogRegR2(ATPU_NDP_glm15)
#Chi2                 14.61609 
#Df                   3 
#Sig.                 0.002175927 
#Cox and Snell Index  0.2041754 
#Nagelkerke Index     0.648061 
#McFadden's R2        0.6035033
```

But what I'm really interested in is determining the predictive power of my model. I'd like to split my data into test and training datasets to do this. I've tried a validation set and cross-validation approach and keep running into technical difficulties. I'm not sure if I really have no predictive power with my model (possible) or if I have an error in my approach/code.

What seemed to be going well was the methodology described here: https://daviddalpiaz.github.io/r4sl/the-caret-package.html

At the end of this message, I've included: column names of my dataset, my reproducible dataset, and the code I tried to use predict using my best model. Things seemed to be working well (as far as I could tell) with the prediction code until I calculated the "test ACC"; I got a result of zero.

```
# test acc
calc_acc(actual = dispersal_tst15$Dispersed_Or_Recruited,
predicted = predict(glm15_train, newdata = dispersal_tst15))
# result is 0?
```

Then, when I tried to calculate the final probabilities, I got the error: "Error in dimnames(out) <- `*vtmp*` : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent". The code I used when I got this error was:

```
head(predict(glm15_train, newdata = dispersal_trn15, type = "prob"))
```

SO! I guess my ultimate question is: am I approaching the prediction correctly? And if so, how can I resolve the errors I'm getting? Ultimately I'd like to assess the predictive accuracy of my top three models. A final note: for the model used in this example (ATPU_NDP_glm15), there were several individuals that did not have information for "fledge date", so the dataset used is ATPU_knownsex_data_NA_FD. Unfortunately, one of the four individuals that dispersed (my target dependent variable) does not have a fledge date and so is removed in this dataset.

I greatly appreciate any help. Code is below.

```
> colnames(ATPU_knownsex_data)
 [1] "Band_Number"            "Dispersed_Or_Recruited" "Sex"                   
 [4] "Hatch_Year"             "Breeding_Success"       "Fledge_Date"           
 [7] "Body_Condition"         "Age_made_decision"      "No_islands_prospected" 
[10] "Max_Monthly_Avg_SST"    "Precipitation"          "Resighting_Score"
```

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(Band_Number = structure(c(11L, 40L, 41L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L), .Label = c("1015-03552", "1015-03563", 
"1015-03607", "1015-03722", "1015-05582", "1015-05802", "1015-08572", 
"1015-08655", "1015-08657", "1015-08678", "1015-08711", "1015-08715", 
"1015-08716", "1015-10245", "1015-10253", "1015-10300", "1015-10301", 
"1015-10339", "1015-10344", "1015-10351", "1015-10395", "1015-10396", 
"1015-10589", "1015-10708", "1015-10769", "1015-10809", "1015-10851", 
"1015-10856", "1015-10873", "1015-10888", "1015-10896", "1015-14521", 
"1015-14539", "1015-14590", "1015-14603", "1015-14632", "1015-14633", 
"1015-14644", "1015-14647", "1015-14654", "1015-14665", "1015-14671", 
"1015-14680", "1015-14686", "1015-15601", "1015-17067", "1015-17592", 
"1015-17600", "1055-10614", "1055-10646", "1055-10674", "1055-10805", 
"1055-18316", "1055-18455", "1055-18832", "1055-18868", "1055-18874", 
"1055-18910", "1055-18926", "1055-19070", "1905-13613", "1905-18557", 
"1905-18575", "1905-18902"), class = "factor"), Dispersed_Or_Recruited = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Hatch_Year = c(2005L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2002L, 2002L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
    2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2009L, 1995L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
    2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 1997L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2008L, 2012L, 2006L, 2006L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 1996L, 1998L, 1995L, 1997L, 1995L, 2001L, 
    2008L, 2004L, 1998L, 1997L, 2001L, 2001L, 1999L), Breeding_Success = c(0.82, 
    0.54, 0.54, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.59, 0.59, 0.82, 0.82, 
    0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.67, 0.65, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 
    0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.61, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 
    0.66, 0.66, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 
    0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.62, 0.62, 0.35, 0.35, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 
    0.54, 0.65, 0.65, 0.61, 0.65, 0.71, 0.62, 0.78, 0.65, 0.61, 
    0.71, 0.71, 0.6), Fledge_Date = c(107.9583333, 102.875, 104.0479167, 
    91.37361111, 91.96944444, 96.02222222, 99.90972222, 84.89583333, 
    94.94444444, 97.375, 103.0347222, 103.125, 105, 107.0208333, 
    107.0208333, 88.94791667, 93.00694444, 91.9375, 91.9375, 
    92.91666667, 93.99652778, 94.91666667, 103.9791667, 104.0381944, 
    94.93055556, 91.95833333, 98, 103.0416667, 104.125, 104.9583333, 
    107.9583333, 109.1666667, 109.2083333, 96.04583333, 97.07986111, 
    100.075, 100.1861111, 101.0034722, 101.0416667, 101.9618056, 
    102.0180556, 106.0486111, 107.0152778, 107.0826389, 95.07083333, 
    81.11111111, 102.0729167, 104.9166667, 89.07291667, 90.11458333, 
    91.04166667, 97.95833333, 90, 94.98611111, 90.40972222, 89.92083333, 
    89.98611111, 99.08611111, 106.9166667, 93, 76, 99.93055556, 
    101, 96.89583333), Body_Condition = c(1.914893617, 1.808510638, 
    1.678082192, 1.804511278, 2.2, 2.147651007, 2.138157895, 
    NA, 1.920529801, 2.071428571, 1.700680272, 1.90647482, 2.013888889, 
    1.901408451, 1.727941176, 2.071428571, 2.035714286, 2.178571429, 
    2.062937063, 1.965517241, 2.178571429, 1.979166667, 2.237762238, 
    2.048611111, 2.446043165, 2.205882353, 2.099236641, 1.866197183, 
    1.603053435, 1.857142857, 1.595744681, 1.766917293, 1.956521739, 
    1.931818182, 1.897810219, 1.978417266, 1.76056338, 1.75862069, 
    2.127659574, 1.934306569, 1.598639456, 1.865671642, 1.678321678, 
    1.785714286, 1.827586207, 2.089552239, 2.092198582, 2.142857143, 
    2.201492537, 1.775362319, 1.793103448, 2.253521127, 1.95035461, 
    2.446043165, 2.276119403, 2.363013699, 2.118055556, 1.847682119, 
    1.793333333, 2.191780822, NA, 2.027027027, 2.092198582, 2.027972028
    ), Age_made_decision = c(7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 
    13L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 17L, 
    16L, 6L, 18L, 8L, 14L, 2L, 11L, 17L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L), No_islands_prospected = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L), Max_Monthly_Avg_SST = c(12.5, 12.7, 12.7, 12.9, 
    12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
    12.5, 12.8, 11.2, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 
    11.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 
    12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 
    11.8, 13.5, 13.3, 13.3, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 11.1, 11.8, 11.2, 
    11.7, 11.2, 13.1, 11.8, 12.5, 11.8, 11.7, 13.1, 13.1, 12.4
    ), Precipitation = c(295.8, 351.2, 351.2, 262.9, 262.9, 262.9, 
    262.9, 187.8, 187.8, 295.8, 295.8, 295.8, 295.8, 295.8, 295.8, 
    334.35, 249.7, 334.35, 334.35, 334.35, 334.35, 334.35, 334.35, 
    334.35, 121.8, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 351.2, 
    351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 
    351.2, 263.6, 174, 469.1, 469.1, 174, 174, 174, 316.5, 120.9, 
    249.7, 121.8, 249.7, 142, 263.6, 199, 120.9, 121.8, 142, 
    142, 152.7), Resighting_Score = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

Here is the code I used to try and make the prediction:

````
#partition the data (70% training; 30% test)
      #creatDataPartition tries to keep similar ratios of variables the same between sets
library(caret)
set.seed(125)
dispersal_glm15 = createDataPartition(ATPU_knownsex_data_NA_FD$Dispersed_Or_Recruited, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)

dispersal_trn15 = ATPU_knownsex_data_NA_FD[dispersal_glm15, ]
dispersal_tst15 = ATPU_knownsex_data_NA_FD[-dispersal_glm15, ]
#had to use the NA dataset to get this to work


#build glm15 on the training dataset
glm15_train = train(form = Dispersed_Or_Recruited ~ Fledge_Date+Age_made_decision+No_islands_prospected, data = test.data1,
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5),
                method = "glm",
                family = "binomial")



trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)[1:3]

#call up the training model
glm15_train
#16 samples; 3 predictors
#5fold cross validation (13,12,13,13,13 sample sizes)
#Resampling results: 
#RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
#0.2309793  0.7605613  0.1333559


#shows all the information stored
names(glm15_train)
#interested in 'results' and 'finalModel'


glm15_train$results
#shows same information as when called the training model 
#not getting the same categories of information as in the tutorial

glm15_train$finalModel
#summary with coefficients; df; null and residual deviance


#not sure what this does
calc_acc = function(actual, predicted) {
mean(actual == predicted)
}

head(predict(glm15_train, newdata = dispersal_tst15))

# test acc
calc_acc(actual = dispersal_tst15$Dispersed_Or_Recruited,
predicted = predict(glm15_train, newdata = dispersal_tst15))
# result is 0?

head(predict(glm15_train, newdata = dispersal_trn15, type = "prob"))
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things before I get to the idea of assessing predictive quality of each of your models.

1. If you're trying to predict dispersal, code it as 1. Its standard procedure to code the "success" or "thing you want to model" as the "positive" case of being 1. But, for now, I'll leave it coded as you have it.
2. Rare events can be tricky in statistical learning. The search term you want to look into is "class imbalance." I wrote a little summary of typical methods for a project for a graduate seminar in statistical computing you can check out [at GitHub.](https://github.com/markhwhiteii/stat-comp/blob/master/docs/manuscript.pdf)
3. But your sample size is too small to do anything meaningful. A dataset of 64 cases with only 3 being in the positive outcome does not give any model much to work with. Especially when some of the most common approaches are things like "throw out data from the class with too many cases until its balanced" (undersampling), which would only leave you with six cases. Since this is for a thesis and learning how to do the modeling, I'll keep going—but just know that the results aren't going to be incredibly useful.
4. You mention violating assumptions of normality and homogeneity of variance—these are assumptions in ordinary least squares regression, but not in a logistic regression like you have here. I'd suggest reading the chapter "Generalized Linear Models" by Coxe, West, and Aiken (2013) in *The Oxford Handbook of Quantitative Methods, Volume II* for a good background on all of the different generalized linear models.

#### Assessing predictive quality

As for actually doing it in R, the people behind the `{caret}` package—and many other programmers—have begun putting all of the machine learning tools into a collection of packages called [tidymodels](https://github.com/tidymodels/tidymodels).

Julia Silge has some good introductions to this on her YouTube page, [like this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPptRkGoYMg)

But what you would do ideally is some type of k-fold cross-validation. Let's say we want to test the specificity and accuracy of your best model. Some annotated code is below. I renamed the dataset to `dat`.

```
library(tidymodels)

# clasification problems want this to be a factor outcome
dat$Dispersed_Or_Recruited <- as.factor(dat$Dispersed_Or_Recruited)

wk <- workflow() # start a workflow for the entire process

# make a recipe of what to do, which in this case is just a formula and data
dat_rec <- recipe(Dispersed_Or_Recruited ~ 
                    Fledge_Date + Age_made_decision + No_islands_prospected, 
                  data = dat)

# make a specification of what type of model you want to build
dat_spec <- logistic_reg() %>% # tell it you want to use logistic regression
  set_engine("glm") # tell it you want to use glm to do so

# add to our workflow
wk <- wk %>% 
  add_recipe(dat_rec) %>% 
  add_model(dat_spec)

# make splits with 5-fold cross-validation
set.seed(1839) # for reproducibility
dat_cv <- vfold_cv(dat, v = 5)

# use fit resamples to fit the model on each fold of the data
fit_out <- fit_resamples(wk, resamples = dat_cv, 
                         # specify metrics better for class imbalance
                         # see ?spec and "Implementation" for explanation
                         metrics = metric_set(spec, accuracy))

# look at metrics
fit_out %>% 
  collect_metrics()
```

First, you'll get some warning messages, like "No true negatives were detected." This makes sense, because your data only had 3 negative cases in it. If you break the data down into 5 chunks, you're going to get folds without any negative outcomes in it. This is where you need a bigger sample size.

You'll also get some errors about the model not converging—again, because of the class imbalance.

But, at the end, you can look at your metrics:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1 accuracy binary     0.923     5  0.0344
2 spec     binary     0.333     3  0.333
```

These are the metrics averaged across all folds that converged, hence `mean` and `n`. You can see your accuracy is good. The data are so imbalanced that if it just predicts a positive case every time, it will have 95.3% accuracy (61 / 64). The specificity, or `spec`, is not so great, since there's so little data of the negative class to train on.

Again, the outputs here and interpreting them aren't too useful—there's not enough data to do much modeling with. But I hope that gets you started at cross-validation metrics, and give you some things to look into (tidymodels, class imbalance, assumptions of general linear models).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I'll take a look at the package and try to emulate your methods. I actually did code dispersal as "1" and recruited as "0", that was a typo last night. I'll edit my question. Thanks for the clarification on the assumptions. I agree that a lot of the solutions to my issue require a larger sample size, but it is still very helpful to run down some of these rabbit holes before I have my full dataset.

Comment: I ran the code you provided and it worked. However, in the final tibble output, I got the "accuracy" row, but the second row was "ppv" for me, instead of the "spec" you obtained. Do you have any ideas how this could have happened? Given the lack of specificity in my model, this is an important output I would like to obtain. Thanks again.

Comment: That's my mistake. I was messing around with putting different metrics in, and I copied over code and then changed it. My fault—but it shows that you can change what metrics you want to see by specifying their functions in `metric_set`